# regex match slow

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, filesystems

I try to let use ajax upload file over 2mb with nodejs app,
client side I use `FileReader` api to save base64 then pass through `FormData`.

My problem is server side code like below so slow, I put `console.log` try to find which part, when upload bigger size file, seems stuck at regex `match`..
any suggestion how to improve this?

https://regex101.com/r/qS2lB2/1

```
...
console.log(image.data_base64);  
// 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/7QAsUGhvd ...
var matches = image.data_base64.match(/^data:.+\/(.+);base64,(.*)$/);
console.log('done');  // slow

var fileExtension = matches[1];
var base64 = matches[2];
var buffer = new Buffer(base64, 'base64');

...
yield Promise.resolve( filesystem().writeFile(temporaryFilePath, buffer) );
```

Comment: You can use `split` instead. For example `image.data_base64.split(/[:;,]/)[1]; //mime type`;

Comment: thanks for reply does split fast than use above regex

Comment: Try [`^data:[^\/]+\/([^;]+);base64,(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/cX0dC1/1) that uses negated character classes in the two first capture groups instead of greedy dot matching patterns that involve much backtracking.

Comment: @Tresdin Thanks this so fast

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks this works!

Comment: do you want to leave answer below

Comment: @user1575921: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you still want to use a regex for some reason, the performance can be improved by replacing non-trailing `.+` subpatterns with appropriate negated character classes that  involve much less backtracking.

Use

```
/^data:[^\/]+\/([^;]+);base64,(.*)$/
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cX0dC1/1).

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `data:` - literal char sequence `data:`
- `[^\/]+` - 1+ characters other than `/`
- `\/` - a literal slash
- `([^;]+)` - Group 1: 1+ characters other than `;`
- `;base64,` - a literal char sequence `;base,`
- `(.*)` - Group 2: 0+ any characters but a newline
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Just note that backtracking means that the greedy pattern grabs all text it can match (with `.+`, it matches all the line) and then tries to accommodate characters for the subsequent subpatterns. Thus, `.+` inside a pattern is not a good idea when your strings are in some way delimited. In these cases, when a delimiter is a single character, negated character classes are best.  If the delimiter is 2+ char long, use lazy dot matching or unrolled patterns (unroll the loop technique).

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, is there a reaison of the `[^\/]+` group (3rd & 4th steps) ?.
`/^data:([^;]+);base64,(.*)$/` should also work the same no ?

Comment: @BastienSander If by "work the same" you mean there will be a match, then [you are right](https://regex101.com/r/cX0dC1/2), but note that the first capturing group will  hold `image/jpeg` and not `jpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

Additional length means there's more string that the regex must travel through.

Testing your regex (using regex101.com, PHP mode) on strings starting with `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9`:

## Characters added | Steps

```
0   | 63
1   | 68
2   | 73
10  | 113
100 | 563
```

Each additional character is 5 steps.

## How to fix the regex

(based on `characters added=100` taking 563 steps)

- Your biggest problems are the `.+`s

  - Replacing the first one with .+? takes it down to 248 steps
  - Replacing the second with `.+?` takes it from 248 to 34 steps

## The cause of performance issues

Catastrophic backtracking. `.+` will eat up the entire string, and if it still needs to find more characters, it has to go back, releasing characters one by one. The `.+?` is lazy, meaning it will try to move on in the regex ASAP, consuming as few characters as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a file base64-encoded in a `multipart/form-data` request is unnecessary. `FileReader` has a `.readAsArrayBuffer()` method that will give you the raw data (as an ArrayBuffer) that you can pass directly to `formData.append()`.

Comment: that because I want to insert the base64 to other json object

Comment: In that case, you're probably better off submitting that other JSON data as a separate part via an additional `formData.append()`, or split out the object into multiple fields (e.g. instead of adding a part with `{"foo": "bar", "baz": "quux"}`, add two extra parts like `formData.append('foo', 'bar'); formData.append('baz', 'quux');`).

Comment: thanks for reply,  I submit data like `"image": { "list:" [ {"id": "int", "description": "text", "base64": "base64", .... }, {}, {}, {} ]}` do you suggest I should separate the base64 and others, why?

Comment: I suggested separating the actual image data because base64 not only incurs processing overhead on both the front end and back end, but it also makes the output larger than the original. The request is already being encoded with `multipart/form-data`, which can handle binary data just fine, so the base64 encoding is not necessary. Adding the image metadata as one or more extra fields/parts in the `multipart/form-data` request is sensible.